# Django admin: Change two unique values in same time

Tags: django, django-admin, admin, formset

I have a model that contains an IntegerField 'order' and I want to change this attribute in admin page. The 'order' attribute is primary. I added this field to list_editable in `MyModelAdmin`. It works properly when I change only one instance but when I want to swap two rows in same time, it doesn't work.

For example:

```
Model1-Order:5 , Model2-Order: 6
```

and in admin page, I change the orders to

```
Model1-Order:6 , Model2-Order: 5
```

it raises an exception.

I searched and found 'formset' but I don't know how to use it in ModelAdmin.